# Rails API for Federated ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, single-sign-on, federated

I am looking for a Rails API  for a federated id service or cloud sso.  I've been playing around with the idea. Of CAS and omniauth but for an enterprise-ish app it would be better if it could auth could be unified across all applications a small biz might use.

Answer (score 0):

There's many different options for a Federated ID using Rails. Gatekeeper is a very good one that I've heard about and most people I know talk about.

Another one that is very young compared to other is oPro which basically simulates OAuth 2 on your Rails App you can find it here [oPro](https://github.com/opro/opro).

In my opinion and experience working with federated IDs in enterprise projects I'd suggest looking into implementing it yourself which is just a matter of following the documentation of whichever one you choose.